# Use page title as text in body

Tags: php, javascript, html, document.write

Im trying to find a way to display the title of the generated page in the body as text. 
I have tried using the following code to display the title.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('You have visited the page ' + document.title );
    </script>
```

Although the code does what i want, i think that i must use another way to do it, more SEO friendly! When i open the page and check the code, i see this code and not the result of (document.title).

Answer (score 1):

Add the title to the server-side script that generates this page. You'll need to post some of your server-side code to get a more specific answer. In general:

```
<?php
$title = "My Page"
echo <<<EOT
<html>
<head>
    <title>$title</title>
</head>
<body>
    You have visited the page $title
</body>
</html>
EOT
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not affect the source code of the page. It gets rendered after the page loads and you see the result. Use PHP for sorting like this.

Answer (score 0):

Any client side generated html isn't going to appear in the source. You need to do it server side, in PHP or whatever, if you want it in the source.